# How can I tap into an ItemView.onShow from CollectionView?

Tags: marionette

I would like to be able to listen on the [show](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#region-events-and-callbacks) event on an itemView from a CollectionView. The following snippet does not work. Perhaps this isn't possible?

```
@on 'itemview:show', (itemView) =>
  console.log "Showed itemView"
```

Comment: Note: this does work if I add the following snippet to the ItemView:

onShow: -> @trigger 'show'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment that you made in your question is the only way to make this work, at the moment.

This is a limitation in how the `onShow` method can be called on item views, because there's no guarantee of when an item view will be shown.